# How to pass request object through Nest.js Guards with Nest.js Passport Module and Passport Discord?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, passport.js, nestjs-passport

I'm working with nest.js as well as it's passport module and passport-discord to handle discord oauth2 authentication.

However, I want to pass the request object from my login route through the authentication guard for use later down the line where I check some of the data, and then will want to invoke the `logOut()` method on the request object in some situations.

**Controller:**

```
@Get('login')
  @UseGuards(DiscordAuthGuard)
  login() {
    console.log('hello123');
  }
```

**Guard:**

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

export class DiscordAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('discord') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const activate = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    await super.logIn(request);
    return activate;
  }
}
```

**Discord Strategy:**

```
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Profile, Strategy } from 'passport-discord';
import { IAuthService } from '../interfaces/auth';
export class DiscordStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    @Inject('AUTH_SERVICE') private readonly authService: IAuthService,
  ) {
    super({
      clientID: 'REDACTED',
      clientSecret: 'REDACTED',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4000/api/auth/redirect',
      scope: ['identify'],
    });
  }

  async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile) {
    console.log('DiscordStrategy Validate Method');
    console.log(profile);
// I WANT TO BE ABLE TO GET THE REQUEST OBJECT TO HERE, SO THAT I CAN PASS IT INTO MY AUTH SERVICE
    return this.authService.validateUser({ discordId: profile.id });
  }
}
```

Any idea how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `passReqToCallback` parameter to super in constructor:

```
constructor(
    @Inject('AUTH_SERVICE') private readonly authService: IAuthService,
  ) {
    super({
      clientID: 'REDACTED',
      clientSecret: 'REDACTED',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4000/api/auth/redirect',
      scope: ['identify'],
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }
```

and modify the validate function to have signature

```
async validate(req: Request, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile)
```